# ArrayList<>.values.toArray, cast to a custom type array

Tags: java, casting

So imagine I have the following: `myList` of type `ArrayList<CustomType>` and I want to convert it to an array, how would I go about this?

I have tried

```
CustomType[] myArr = (CustomType)myList.toArray();
```

This compile, no problem but I get a casting exception at runtime. My current solution is iterating through the ArrayList and writing each entry into the array, not good.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a version of toArray that takes a type

[toArray(T[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

So you would do:

```
myList.toArray(new CompositeType[myList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

myList.toArray(new CustomType[myList.size]);

Comment: size is a method. You have missed method paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

The toArray() method without passing any argument returns Object[]. So you have to pass an array as an argument, which will be filled with the data from the list, and returned. You can pass an empty array as well, but you can also pass an array with the desired size.

CustomType[] array = myList.toArray(new CustomType[list.size()]);

Answer (score 0):

Your myArr is an Array of CustomType, you cannot cast a CustomType object to a CustomType Array object. Do this:

```
CustomType[] myArr = (CustomType[])myList.toArray();
```